# Changing an image in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, image, switch-statement

I have an image in my HTML, but i would like to change the image when an answer is given by the user. For some reason the first function works, but the image doesn't change.. Can someone help me please.

This is my code so far:

```
window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';

    var showMessage = function (text) {
        var messageCenter = document.getElementById('messageCenter');
        messageCenter.innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>\n";
    };

    var checkName = function (name) {
        switch (prompt("What is your name?")) {
            case "Leonard":
                showMessage("Leonard! How did I not recognize you! Why would you like to get rid of me!");
                break;
            case "Penny":
                showMessage("Penny Penny Penny! You've got so much to learn.");
                break;
            case "Howard":
                showMessage("Howard, the only one without a Ph.D");
                break;
            case "Raj":
                showMessage("Interesting. You're afraid of insects and women. Ladybugs must render you catatonic!");
                break;
            default:
                showMessage("Well, I'm not familiair with you. I don't like to talk to strange people.");
                break;
        }
    };
    checkName()

    var myImage = document.getElementById('sheldon');
    var checkCase = function (img) {
        switch (img) {
            case "Leonard":
                myImage("verbaasd.jpg");
                break;
            case "Penny":
                myImage("les.jpg");
                break;
            case "Howard":
                myImage("howard.jpg");
                break;
            case "Raj":
                myImage("loser.jpg");
                break;
            default:
                myImage("sheldon.jpg");
                break;
        }
    };
    checkCase()
};
```

Comment: You can do this in the `switch` block, or in the `showMessage` function, or in another function.  Have you tried?  In what way did that attempt not work?

Comment: Why don't you give that a try and let us know how it works!

Comment: Teacher said I had to use another function, but I don't know how to start :(

Comment: Doesn't `checkCase()` take 1 argument?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `myImage()`. You set this variable with a DOM object and call it as a normal function. This gives you an error. You also forgot to store the name and pass it as argument to your checking functions.

Your code should be:

```
window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';

    var name = prompt("What is your name?");

    var showMessage = function showMessage(text) {
        var messageCenter = document.getElementById('messageCenter');
        messageCenter.innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>\n";
    };

    var checkName = function (name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "Leonard":
                showMessage("Leonard! How did I not recognize you! Why would you like to get rid of me!");
                break;
            case "Penny":
                showMessage("Penny Penny Penny! You've got so much to learn.");
                break;
            case "Howard":
                showMessage("Howard, the only one without a Ph.D");
                break;
            case "Raj":
                showMessage("Interesting. You're afraid of insects and women. Ladybugs must render you catatonic!");
                break;
            default:
                showMessage("Well, I'm not familiair with you. I don't like to talk to strange people.");
                break;
        }
    };
    checkName(name);

    var myImage = function myImage(img) {
        var sheldon = document.getElementById('sheldon');
        sheldon.innerHTML = '<img src="' + img + '"/>';
    };

    var checkCase = function (name) {
        switch (name) {
            case "Leonard":
                myImage("verbaasd.jpg");
                break;
            case "Penny":
                myImage("les.jpg");
                break;
            case "Howard":
                myImage("howard.jpg");
                break;
            case "Raj":
                myImage("loser.jpg");
                break;
            default:
                myImage("sheldon.jpg");
                break;
        }
    };
    checkCase(name);
};
```

Now your `myImage()` is a function which insert a new image inside a container with ID `sheldon`.

If you don't want to have a container for the image, and instead you want reference directly to the image, can change the `myImage()` function in:

```
    var myImage = function myImage(img) {
        var sheldon = document.getElementById('sheldon');
        sheldon.src = img;
    };
```

BTW, I see that you're learning so it's right to start from the basics, but remember that there are cleaner ways to do that.

Hope it's helpful to you.